# Perimeter of triangle $\triangle PQR \ge \frac{1}{2}\cdot$ perimeter of triangle $\triangle ABC$.

Tags: geometry, inequality

Given triangle $\triangle ABC$. There are $P,Q,R$ in $BC,CA,AB$ satisfying $AQ+AR=BP+BR=CQ+CP$. Prove that the perimeter of triangle $\triangle PQR$ is not less than $1/2$ of the perimeter of triangle $\triangle ABC$. I have an idea.
If we set the perimeter of triangle $ABC=S$ then $AQ+AR=S/3$. We have $[AQR]+[BPR]+[CQP]=2AQ\cdot AP\cdot \sin A+2BP\cdot BR\cdot \sin B+ 2CQ\cdot CP\cdot \sin C \le S/18\cdot(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C) \le S/18\cdot3\sqrt{3}/2=S\sqrt{3}/12$.
I'm trying to find an inequality relating the circumference and the area of ​​a triangle in which the area is in the larger dimension but is probably not feasible.

Please share your opinion, I am very grateful for it.

Comment: I think the condition $AR+AQ=BP+BR=...$ only is for equilateral triangle. in this case $S_{PQR}= \frac 12 S_{ABC}$. I could not construct other cases.